# How to Copy an ISO file from my computer to Remote Hyper-V 2019 Host (Over the internet)?

Tags: hyper-v-server-2019

I have freshly installed Microsoft Hyper-V 2019 (Free), in Remote Datacenter (Different country)

but I can't find a way to upload the ISO files to start installing the Operating Systems

So, How to Copy an ISO file from my computer to Remote Hyper-V 2019 Host (Over the internet) ?

Comment: You aren't using Hyper-V Manager to operate your server?

Comment: I am using it, but there is no single option to upload a file to the Host, I spent hours trying to find a solution for that

Comment: I am extremely unable to understand why Microsoft did not put an option to upload file to the Hyper-V server.

Comment: Apparently you need to have access to a storage or host server disk in the DC where you can put your ISO file. Hyper-V itself doesn't provide a storage.

Comment: Just open windows explorer to \\your-hyperv-server\c$ and copy the files

Comment: unfortunately, that is not working because it is over the internet